# embedding local characters to global (Hecke) characters

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-analysis, characters

Let $F$ be a number field, and $S$ be a non-empty finite set of places of $F$. Suppose that for each $v\notin S$, we have a character $\chi_v$ of $F_v^\times$ (for my purpose, we can require that $\chi_v$ is quadratic). Moreover we suppose that $\chi_v$ is unramifiedd for almost all $v\notin S$. Is it possible to find a global Hecke character $\chi$ of $\textbf{A}_F^\times$ such that for all $v\notin S$, the local component of $\chi$ is exactly $\chi_v$?

If $S$ has a single element $v_1$, I think this is possible by the following simple construction. For $a\in F^\times$, define 
$$\chi_{v_1}(a)=\prod_{v\ne v_1}\chi_v(a)^{-1},$$
and then extend $\chi_{v_1}$ to $F_{v_1}^\times$ by density.

According the comments given by @znt this is false. Now my question is: is there any reasonable conditions on $\chi_v$ for $v\notin S$ such that this is true? If this is not suitable for this site, I will delete it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This clearly can't be done, because there are uncountably many choices for the local places, but only countably many for the global ones. A special case of your question would be something like "Let me choose a finite set S, and then for every prime not in S let me tell you whether it will split or be inert. Now find a quadratic extension that does the job". The problem is that a Hecke character has to be trivial on the global elements, so there are very delicate compatibilities.

Comment: As for your construction, if I define a function from Q^* to C^* by choosing a random set of primes and sending them to +1, and the rest to -1, then this will almost never be continuous for any topology induced by completion of Q, and a random discontinuous function can't be extended by density.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is there any reasonable condition that can be imposed on $\chi_v, v\notin S$ such that this is true?